# SQL SELECT and JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Hello all i need a little bit help in MySQL query. 
I have 2 table and need to find out which value exist in table A that doesn't exist in table B where in table B the values that are to be compared should have the month column value be of current month.

table A

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
| 4    |
| 5    |
+------+
```

table B

```
+------+-----+
| id   |Month|
+------+-----+
| 1    |March|
| 2    |March|
| 3    |April|
+------+-----+
```

I want to show all the values from table A that doesn't exist in table b for the month of April. 
Like id 3 has paid fee of April but id 1 and 2 hasn't paid.

The result table should look like this.

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
+------+
```

I have tried multiple queries like

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id WHERE B.id IS NULL and B.month=(current date)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN (select * from B where month=(current month)) ON A.id = B.id WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

I don't understand what i am doing wrong in this. Sorry for any typo mistake since this has been posted by mobile.

Comment: "find out which value exist in table A that doesn't exist in table B".  So why the result is not id 4 and 5?  It exists in Table A, but not Table B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Show all the values from table A that dosn't exist in table b for the month of April*

```
select * from A where id not in (select id from B where Month = 'April')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add more condition in table A because it doesn't have a "month" column. And since your "month" value in table b is string ("March" instead of "3"), you have to define that as well. You can try this query and see if it works.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) AS "curMonth" FROM A) a LEFT JOIN B ON a.id=b.id AND curmonth=MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(b.month,'%b'));
```

You could also play with the query a bit. Let say you want to see previous month or one month in advance, you could add `INTERVAL` condition. This condition can also cater for current month.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 0 MONTH)) AS "curMonth" FROM A) a LEFT JOIN B ON a.id=b.id AND curmonth=MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(b.month,'%b'));
```

You can change to `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` for previous month data from current date, `INTERVAL 0 MONTH` for current month data and `INTERVAL -1 MONTH` for any 1 month in advance data.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TableB)
```

This will get all rows from TableA that are not in tableB.

This works in SQL server, but I'm not sure about MySQL.

Comment: Then don't post `SQL Server` answer.  OP specifically tag `MySQL` in the question.  Will this answer be useful if it doesn't work in MySQL?  No.

Comment: well ok but you don't have to be that mean.